# Illegal Instruction when running python3 installed with linuxbrew

Tags: linux, python-3.x, python-3.5, linuxbrew

I'm installing this in a shared filesystem (so hosts`a`, through `f` all have my `$HOME` directory on them and it's synced between them relatively instantly).

I only get this error on a few of the hosts. For example, I ran `brew install python3` on `b` and it works fine there and on `a` and `d`, but on `e` and `f`, I get `Illegal Instruction` or `Illegal Instruction (core dumped)` depending on the host.

Any help would be vastly appreciated.

Comment: I just did this too and system a (the one I used to install python via linux brew) it works fine. But on system b its says illegal instruction.